# Statistical Mode with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I have a table that has this schema:

```
create table mytable (creation_date timestamp,
                      value int,
                      category int);
```

I want the maximum ocurrence of a value every each hour per category, Only on week days. I had made some progress, I have a query like this now:

```
select category,foo.h as h,value, count(value) from mytable, (
      select date_trunc('hour', 
                        '2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp+generate_series(0,23)*'1 hour'::interval)::time as h) AS foo 
      where date_part('hour',creation_date) = date_part('hour',foo.h) and
            date_part('dow',creation_date) > 0 and date_part('dow',creation_date) < 6
      group by category,h,value;
```

as result I got something like this:

```
category |    h     |  value  | count 
---------+----------+---------+-------
       1 | 00:00:00 |       2 |     1
       1 | 01:00:00 |       2 |     1
       1 | 02:00:00 |       2 |     6
       1 | 03:00:00 |       2 |    31
       1 | 03:00:00 |       3 |    11
       1 | 04:00:00 |       2 |    21
       1 | 04:00:00 |       3 |     9
       1 | 13:00:00 |       1 |    14
       1 | 14:00:00 |       1 |    10
       1 | 14:00:00 |       2 |     7
       1 | 15:00:00 |       1 |    52
```

for example at 04:00 I have to values 2 and 3, with counts of 21 and 9 respectively, I only need the value with highest count which would be the statiscal mode.

BTW I have more than 2M records

Comment: What version of postgres are you using and what would you want to happen if there are two different values which have the same count?  eg: if 1,04:00:00,3,11 was 1,04:00:00,3,21 instead?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4, if two values have the same count I need the lowest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simpler:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (category, extract(hour FROM creation_date)::int)
       category
     , extract(hour FROM creation_date)::int AS h
     , count(*)::int AS max_ct
     , value
FROM   mytable
WHERE  extract(isodow FROM creation_date) < 6 -- no sat or sun
GROUP  BY 1,2,4
ORDER  BY 1,2,3 DESC;
```

#### Basically these are the steps:

1. Exclude weekends (`WHERE ...`). Use [ISODOW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to simplify the expression.
2. Extract `hour` from `timestamp` as  `h`.
3. Group by `category`, `h` and `value`.
4. Count the rows per combination of the three; cast to `integer` -  we don't need `bigint`.
5. Order by `category`, `h` and the highest count (`DESC`).
6. Only pick the first row (highest count) per `(category, h)` with the according `category`.

I am able to do this in one query level, because `DISTINCT` is applied *after* the aggregate function.

The result will hold *no* rows for any `(category, h)` without no entries at all. If you need to fill in the blanks, `LEFT JOIN` to this:

```
SELECT c.category, h.h
FROM   cat_tbl c
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0, 23) AS h) h
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of your table, I'd be tempted to use your query to build a temporary table, then run a query on that to finalise the results.

Assuming you called the temporary table "summary_table", the following query should do it.

```
select
    category, h, value, count
from
    summary_table s1
where
    not exists 
    (select * from summary_table s2
        where s1.category = s2.category and
                  s1.h = s2.h and
                   (s1.count < s2.count 
            OR (s1.count = s2.count and s1.value > s2.value));
```

If you don't want to create a table, you could use a WITH clause to attach your query to this one.

```
with summary_table as (
select category,foo.h as h,value, count(value) as count from mytable, (
      select date_trunc('hour', 
                        '2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp+generate_series(0,23)*'1 hour'::interval)::time as h) AS foo 
      where date_part('hour',creation_date) = date_part('hour',foo.h) and
            date_part('dow',creation_date) > 0 and date_part('dow',creation_date) < 6
      group by category,h,value)
select
    category, h, value, count
from
    summary_table s1
where
    not exists 
    (select * from summary_table s2
        where s1.category = s1.category and
                  s1.h = s2.h and
                   (s1.count < s2.count 
            OR (s1.count = s2.count and s1.value > s2.value));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the query didn't work, it worked if I put the second subquery in the from clause, like this: `from summary_table s1 (select * from summary_table) as s2 where where s1.category = s1.category and
                  s1.h = s2.h and
                   (s1.count < s2.count 
            OR (s1.count = s2.count and s1.value > s2.value));`